# R export table of dataframe with second ID variable acting as column split

Tags: html, r, html-table, latex, knitr

I have the following (example) data summary table in R that has two ID columns, `year` and `group`:

```
input <- as.data.frame(cbind(year = c(2000, 2000, 2001, 2001),
             group = c(0 ,1 , 0 , 1),
             count = c(5, 10, 6, 12),
             shares = c(5/15, 10/15, 6/18, 12/18)))

# input
#   year group count    shares
# 1 2000     0     5 0.3333333
# 2 2000     1    10 0.6666667
# 3 2001     0     6 0.3333333 
# 4 2001     1    12 0.6666667
```

I would like to export this as a table to latex/html with the `group` ID acting as a column split as follows:

```
| year |  count   |   shares  | 
|      | 0  |  1  |  0  |  1  | 
| ---- | -- | --- | --- | --- | 
| 2000 | 5  | 10  | .33 | .67 | 
| 2001 | 6  | 12  | .33 | .67 |
```

Is there a package in R that makes this possible?

So far, I have looked at `Stargazer`, which doesn't seem to support this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `knitr` with `kableextra` for this.
Your example would be (I use `latex` output here, you can adjust/switch to `html` with `knitr::kable(format = "html")` ):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)

input %>% 
  gather(var, value, -year, -group) %>% 
  unite(group, c("var", "group"), sep = "_", remove = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(group, value) %>% 
  set_names("year", "0", "1", "0", "1") %>% 
  knitr::kable(escape = F, format = "latex") %>% 
  add_header_above(c(" ", "count" = 2, "shares" = 2))
```

`latex` output is:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|r|r|r|r}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{count} & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{shares} \\
\cline{2-3} \cline{4-5}
year & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\hline
2000 & 5 & 10 & 0.3333333 & 0.6666667\\
\hline
2001 & 6 & 12 & 0.3333333 & 0.6666667\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

`html` out is:

```html
<table>
 <thead>
<tr>
<th style="border-bottom:hidden" colspan="1"></th>
<th style="border-bottom:hidden; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;text-align: center; " colspan="2"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px;">count</div></th>
<th style="border-bottom:hidden; padding-bottom:0; padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;text-align: center; " colspan="2"><div style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; padding-bottom: 5px;">shares</div></th>
</tr>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> year </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> 0 </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> 1 </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> 0 </th>
   <th style="text-align:right;"> 1 </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2000 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 5 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 10 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.3333333 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.6666667 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 2001 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 6 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 12 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.3333333 </td>
   <td style="text-align:right;"> 0.6666667 </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Documentation can be found in the [kableextra vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#add_header_rows_to_group_columns)

Answer (score 2):

An additional solution *for HTML output only* is offered by the [htmlTable package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/general.html):

```
require(tidyverse)
require(htmlTable)

fortable <- input %>% 
  gather(var, value, -year, -group) %>% 
  unite(group, c("var", "group"), sep = "_", remove = TRUE) %>% 
  spread(group, value)

htmlTable(fortable,
          header = paste(c("year", "0", "1", "0", "1")),
          rnames = FALSE,
          cgroup = paste(c(" ", "count", "shares")),
          n.cgroup = c(1,2,2))
```